# MS Access filter date range on GROUP BY month report

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm stumped over something probably simple. I'm grouping results by month and I want to filter it by a date range. I have a GROUP BY query shown below.

```
PARAMETERS ShipDateStart DateTime, ShipDateEnd DateTime;
SELECT Month([ORDERS].[ShipDate]) & '/01/' & Right(Year([orders].[ShipDate]),2) AS ShipDateName, Sum(IIf([ORDERS].[ShipDate]-IIf(IsNull([ORDERS].[PromisedDate]),[ORDERS].[EstimatedDate],[ORDERS].[PromisedDate])<=0,1,0)) AS OnTimeYes, Sum(IIf([ORDERS].[ShipDate]-IIf(IsNull([ORDERS].[PromisedDate]),[ORDERS].[EstimatedDate],[ORDERS].[PromisedDate])>0,1,0)) AS OnTimeNo, Year([orders].[ShipDate]) AS ShipDateYear
FROM OrderLineStatus INNER JOIN (DEST INNER JOIN ORDERS ON DEST.DestID = ORDERS.DestID) ON OrderLineStatus.OrderLineStatusID = ORDERS.OrderLineStatusID
WHERE (((DEST.Destination)<>"Purchased" And (DEST.Destination)<>"STOCKED") AND ((OrderLineStatus.OrderLineStatus)="Shipped") AND ((ORDERS.PromisedDate) Is Not Null) AND ((ORDERS.ShipDate) Between [ShipDateStart] And [ShipDateEnd]))
GROUP BY Month([ORDERS].[ShipDate]) & '/01/' & Right(Year([orders].[ShipDate]),2), Year([orders].[ShipDate]), Month([ORDERS].[ShipDate])
ORDER BY Year([orders].[ShipDate]), Month([ORDERS].[ShipDate]);
```

This query works fine. I enter the two parameters and it returns what I want. The problem is that when I'm opening a report with this query as the record source, it asks for the parameters and I can not figure out a way to pass parameters to the query without Access asking for them. The following does not work and it still asks for the parameters.

```
sWhere = "[ShipDateStart] = #" & Format(CDate(Me.StartDateBox), "mm/dd/yyyy") & _
       " 00:00# AND [ShipDateEnd] = #" & Format(CDate(Me.EndDateBox), "mm/dd/yyyy") & _
       " 23:59#"
stDocName = "ShippingOnTimePSD"
DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acPreview, , sWhere, acWindowNormal
```

There are two controls on a form for the dates and a button that runs this code. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DoCmd.SetParameter` to set the parameters before opening the report:

```vb
DoCmd.SetParameter "ShipDateStart", "#" & Format(CDate(Me.StartDateBox), "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#"
DoCmd.SetParameter "ShipDateEnd", "#" & Format(CDate(Me.EndDateBox), "mm/dd/yyyy") & " 23:59#"
DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acPreview, , , acWindowNormal
```

Comment: This is a step in the right direction as it doesn't pop up asking for the parameters, but it returns with no results. I enter the same values in the report parameter values manually and it works just fine so I have no idea what's wrong. The form controls retrieve the dates and CDate works, but it's as if the SetParameter entered Null.

Comment: Apparently, Access does some weird typecasting when using `DoCmd.SetParameter` and date parameters. The current edit should work.

Comment: That was it! I thought CDate converted it to a date rendering the "#" prefix/suffix redundant (or possibly problematic as it might turn into "##" prefix/suffix). Oh, well. If it isn't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: Well, that's where I went wrong too, but apparently, `DoCmd.SetParameter` takes an SQL expression string, so your date gets cast back to a string (something that you would type in an SQL statement) and then casts your date to that, with weird effects. E.g. `#1-1-2001#` somehow gets cast to `#8-7-1894#`

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: `#1-1-2001#` will not be casted, but `1-1-2001` will as it is numeric and equals -2001. And `CDate(-2001)` returns the date 1894-07-08 as it is 2001 days before 1899-12-30. However, `CDate("1-1-2001")` will return 2001-01-01.

Comment: @Gustav The thing is, `CDate("1-1-2001")` will get cast to a string `"1-1-2001"` first, which gets processed to -2001, and then gets cast back to a date. So you will have to enter a string expression in `DoCmd.SetParameter` when working with dates

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: Yes, the parameter must _always_ be a string expression, not only for date values. I commented your _somehow_ which intimated some unknown magic or uncertainty.